# Does kylin update aggregates on joined tables

Tags: join, druid, kylin

We have 3 tables which are updated daily. In one of the query these 3 tables are joined and the final joined table has timestamp column. Final joined table is used to compute various aggregates. This query runs everyday and hence everyday join is performed on entire data (not incremental data) and aggregates are calculated.

Question is can this be optimised using Kylin or Druid or any other method? Since 3 tables are updated on daily basis, ideally only this part (incremental) should be joined with the rest of the data in some intelligent way and aggregates should be computed/updated on incremental basis. I believe this would speed up the performance as well.

Comment: Please expand your question. There are a lot of things which are unclear:
1. Where do you have those tables? 
2. Why do you think Druid or Kylin might help? For example, Druid doesn't support joins at all.
3. Are you asking about data modelling or about a specific database features?

Comment: Hi Artem, I am not sure if Druid or Kylin would help here. What I am basically looking at is whether it is possible to compute join on incremental data - whether any tool supports that or if I can develop any logic for that. As I said 3 base tables (say A, B, C) are data-warehouse tables which are loaded/appended on daily bases. One of the tables in this contains time-stamp column (say A0. When I join 3 tables (A, B, C) let us say I get final table as (X). Then (X) is used to compute various aggregates which feed into reports. This join operation is performed daily which I think is not needed.

Comment: Lets say my base tables (A, B, C) contain 1 year worth of history. In that case I can join A, B, C for 1 year worth of data and create a new table X. Now when incremental data (next days data) comes in A, B, C - I need to update X. While updating X I dont want to (re)compute join on entire 1 year + 1 day data. But do something intelligent and update X in such a way that it reflects 1 year + 1 day worth of joined data. Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, I got it. If you always join only the latest data to the latest data, then you'll potentially be able to implement incremental join yourself. Let's say you have table ABC_joined.  Take your latest data that came to A, B, C and put it into tables A_latest, B_latest, C_latest. Join them and then add the result as a new partition for a specified period to ABC_joined. It will join only in a warehouse were partition replacement is supported(BigQuery, Hive) and if you join always the latest data together and never join latest data with historical data